# ¿Por qué 'clepsidra' se escribe sin h?

Tags: etimología

Haciendo 'zapping' en internet sobre relojes de arena me encontré con que son los sucesores de los relojes de agua o Clepsidra.

[Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clepsidra):

> Clepsidra o reloj de agua (del griego κλέπτειν kleptein, 'robar'; ὕδωρ
>   hidor, 'agua') es cualquier mecanismo para medir el tiempo mediante el
>   flujo regulado de un líquido hacia o desde un recipiente graduado,
>   dando así dos tipos diferentes de relojes según la dirección del flujo

Inmediatamente me llama la atención ver que todos los derivados de 'hidor/hidro=agua/líquido' como hidráulico, hídrico, hidrostático, hidratación, etc. se escriben con h mientras 'clepsidra' no tiene la h intermedia que debería tener.

¿Alguien sabe porqué? ¿existe alguna regla para cuando no es prefijo sino sufijo se pierde la h?

Comment: La [RAE dice](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9RnDAoO) de su etimología _Del lat. clepsy̆dra, y este del gr. κλεψύδρα klepsýdra_. Por lo que parece una palabra antigua que viene del latín directamente; por contra, todas aquellas que usan hidro- suelen ser o bien de nueva creación, en las que se "jugó" a usar latín (hidrógeno), o bien tenían la _h_ inicialmente. Añado: veo que [anhidro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2gK2L5Y) es del tipo de clepsidra, _Del gr. ἄνυδρος ánydros 'que no tiene agua'._, lo que tira por tierra lo dicho antes :S

Comment: @fedorqui Una vez más, creo que tu comentario merece convertirse en respuesta. Tal vez con algún añadido sobre lo que menciona Rodrigo en el suyo.

Comment: @Gorpik uy, pero si no conseguí concluir nada. Dado que nunca estudié latín, todo lo que pueda decir será a base de coger referencias de aquí y de allí. Mejor espero a que Rodrigo, Yay o alguien más pueda ofrecer una respuesta con mejor bagaje.

Comment: @fedorqui Bueno, que la palabra no lleva h porque viene del latín y no directamente del griego me parece suficiente conclusión :) Luego Rodrigo ha explicado por qué en latín no lleva h. Y no veo qué le puede faltar a la respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Bueno, contesto para que los comentarios no se pierdan</sub>

La RAE dice de la etimología de [clepsidra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9RnDAoO):

> Del lat. clepsy̆dra, y este del gr. κλεψύδρα klepsýdra.

Por lo que parece una palabra antigua que viene del latín directamente, donde ya no existía dicha *h*.

Por contra, todas aquellas que usan *hidro-* suelen ser:

- o bien de nueva creación, en las que se "jugó" a usar latín ([hidrógeno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KKVuUmz)). Esto versión del latín suele ser denominada [neolatín](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neolat%C3%ADn) y se usó especialmente en el lenguaje científico.
- o bien tenían la *h* inicialmente.

---

Sin embargo, encuentro lo que parece un contraejemplo: [anhidro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2gK2L5Y) es del tipo de clepsidra, donde ya no existía la *h* pero se introdujo posteriormente:

> Del gr. ἄνυδρος ánydros 'que no tiene agua'.

Consultando en el [Mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) veo que esta palabra es relativamente reciente, introducida en 1884 en el fragor de los descubrimientos químicos de la época. Yo lo interpreto pues como otro caso del uso de un latín de nuevo cuño como el antes descrito y, por tanto, independiente de las reglas de evolución de la lengua. Por tanto, no parece que contravenga lo dicho antes.

Comment: Interesante lo de anhidro.